# onBackBtn=minimize does not change the back button behavior

Tags: sygic

In the settings_overload.ini we have defined `onBackBtn=minimize` but this doesn't seem to work.
We still get the question 'Do you want to exit Sygic GPS Navigation?'. We would like to keep the navigation running into background.

We are using Sygic app v 20.0.3 and the file is in the correct folder

can you help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 20.0.0 the location of the files are not more on `sdcard\sygicnavigation\android`, but you need to set the files in `sdcard\Android\data\com.sygic.fleet\files\sygicnavigation\android`